# Concurrent addition and subtraction

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

What happens when two threads try to modify the same property at the exact same time? For instance, if I have an `int value = 0` and I have thread A `value += 5` and thread B `value -= 3`, what happens? I should get the same result no matter which order the threads access the variable in, but I imagine they can access that variable at the EXACT same time.

Comment: _"I should get the same result no matter which order the threads access the variable in"_ But it turns out that you don't.

Comment: @Radiodef: thank you for the response, but could you please explain? if thread A gets there first and then thread B, or vice versa, value should still be 2, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't get the same result. Even though the operation is simple, it is not an atomic operation w.r.t the processor. Simply speaking, the processor needs to fetch the value from the memory to its register, conduct arithmetic instructions and store the value back to the memory. Therefore, they may get the same value of 0 and the value stored back depends on which is the last.

The result you may get will vary from different runs, it could be 5, -3, 2

Comment: oh i see. what kind of results would i get then?

Comment: undetermined.. you have a data race, you may get different result for different runs.

Comment: @user2905368: with `value` not being volatile and no synchronized blocks, it's quite likely that `value` will be 5 in thread A _and_ -3 in thread B, simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact same time in Computer. It is one nano second or less for one thread and then for the other. It is called time slicing. For us `+=` and `-=` might be single operations but for the Processor those are multiple instructions.

The above code without synchronization will cause in race condition and will not guarantee same value all the time.